# "search.exclude" is not working in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I get it there are special cases but I cannot exclude my folder from search in VSCode no matter what I do!

I have this in my `settings.json`

```json
"search.exclude": {
    "node_modules": true,
    "saving/client/hls/**/*.*": true
}
```

and yet I see the results from `saving/client/hls/` folder.

Comment: Are you sure the `*.*` wildcard works as expected? What if you change it to `saving/client/hls/**/*`?

Comment: that worked! please make it an answer!

Comment: i am an old school fella, we used to use `*.*` for files and stuffs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here most likely involves the wildcard that you used.

The correct way to ignore all files under that directory is this

```json
"saving/client/hls/**/*": true
```